# CSS puts a part of the selection list outside of the view

Tags: html, css, selection

Can anyone help me with this?
It just does not look good when the beginning of this list is gone.

fiddle: [Here is a working example](https://jsfiddle.net/2da1svLu/1/)

```
</select>
      </div>
    </section>
    <select class="js-source-states" style="display: none;">
      <optgroup label="">
        <option value='0' selected='selected'>*ALL*</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="">
        <option value='69'>Bert Deraedt</option>
        <option value='96'>Etienne Scherpereel</option>
        <option value='95'>Thomas Roost</option>
        <option value='56'>Unknown</option>
      </optgroup>
      <optgroup label="">
        <option value='57'>Debeuf H</option>
        <option value='17'>Jan Quequin</option>
        <option value='80'>Jovan</option>
        <option value='38'>Koen De Volder</option>
        <option value='81'>Kurt Vancauwenberghe</option>
        <option value='85'>Louis Soet.?</option>
        <option value='31'>Sven Vandekerckhove</option>
        <option value='39'>Tarcy Verzele</option>
      </optgroup>          
    </select>
</div>
```

[image] with Chrome

[image] with Internet Explorer 11

Comment: Just a comment: there is a  bad `</optgroup>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to modified your bootstrap `row` class or add a class to overwrite current negative margin.

add:

```
.row {    
    margin-left: 0; 
}
```

**[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaromenendez/2da1svLu/4/)**

Comment: Hi, It workes like a charm ! thx a lot. I will set this answer as Correct but it seems I have to wait 5 minutes???

Comment: Glad I could help. would luck with your project.

Comment: Wouldn't do that though. You mess with the base of bootstrap layout.

Comment: And that'w why I said he could add a class in the "row" container to overwritte the "row" property just in the container that needs it

Comment: Yep.. you said. Add a class. And if the CSS is in the page itself, which it seems to be, it does not really matter that much. ..  ;-)